# Php mcrypt isn't working properly

Tags: php, mcrypt

I have this code:

```
$original = 'zner5';
$new = mcrypt_decrypt( MCRYPT_3DES, 'keyCodeEncryption', 'C¹`Û‡”fa', 'ecb');
if( $original == $new)
{
    echo "$original == $new";
}
else
{
    echo "$original != $new";
}
```

It outputs 'zner5 != zner5'. Why?

Comment: Does !strcmp($original,$new) work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seem to remember hitting this issue myself some time ago, and if I recall correctly, mcrypt_decrypt() might give you a binary string with extra zero bytes on the end, so try this:

```
$new = trim(mcrypt_decrypt(...));
```

Comment: Note: You'll probably need trim(mcrypt_decrypt(...), "\0") in the case where your original string has whitespace padding that you want to remain intact.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [strcmp](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcmp.php) instead of `==` to test equality.